# Modify Section Title in Document

Tags: sectioning, formatting, memoir

I'm using `memoir` class. I'm trying to make `section` title that ends with a single dot. The section title would be in `sans-serif` font. I've searched for a while but still no luck. Here's my MWE. Thanks.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setsecnumformat{}
\def\sectionmark#1{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\setaftersecskip{-1em}
\begin{document}
\section{My First Section Title}
\lipsum[1-3]
\section{Another Section Title}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Here's my result for now.

[image]

Comment: I don't know about the dot, but there is a class macro, which allows the definition of the font family etc.: `\setsecheadstyle{\sffamily\bfseries}` in the preamble should do that for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a style like

```
\newcommand{\dotsec}[1]{%
\Large\raggedright\sffamily\bfseries #1.}
```

and then declare

```
\setsecheadstyle{\dotsec}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setsecnumformat{}
\def\sectionmark#1{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\setaftersecskip{-1em}
\newcommand{\dotsec}[1]{%
\Large\raggedright\sffamily\bfseries #1.}
\setsecheadstyle{\dotsec}
\begin{document}
\section{My First Section Title}
\lipsum[1-3]
\section{Another Section Title}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]